# how to get textbox data from GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I create GridView, and row have textbox like this.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="00-03">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Text1"  runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("p1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I type in the textbox, and try this code to get the data

```
TextBox1.Text = targetgridview.Rows[0].Cells[3].Text;
```

but i get empty

before this textbox,they have three Label,but when use `Cells[0]` or `Cells[1]`..`Cells[3]`,`i` get data

i don't why i can get data from `Label`, but can't get data form textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `TemplateFields` with real controls you have to use `GridViewRow.FindControl("ID")` to get the reference to the control:

```
TextBox Text1 = (TextBox) targetgridview.Rows[0].FindControl("Text1");
TextBox1.Text = Text1.Text;
```